# @EnableTransactionManager java config

Tags: spring, transactions

When @EnableTransactionManager is not set, there are no errors.

But when @EnableTransactionManager is set, an initializing error occurs.

Here is `catalina.out` log and my java config file:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("net.myproject.db")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${statdb.driverClassName}")
    private String statdbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${statdb.url}")
    private String statdbUrl;

    @Value("${statdb.id}")
    private String statdbId;

    @Value("${statdb.pw}")
    private String statdbPw;

    @Value("${statdb.validationQuery}")
    private String statdbValidationQuery;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceStatdb() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(statdbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(statdbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(statdbId);
        dataSource.setPassword(statdbPw);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(statdbValidationQuery);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSourceStatdb());
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceStatdb());
        sessionFactory.setMapperLocations( new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:mybatis/query/*.xml"));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory());
    }
}
```

```
 ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:470) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:786)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3589a9d0.transactionInterceptor(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3589a9d0.CGLIB$transactionAdvisor$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3589a9d0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$29be3905.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:293)
    at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3589a9d0.transactionAdvisor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'transactionManager' is required
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(TransactionAspectSupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 86 more
```

On my local environment there are no errors, and the Spring context initializes successfully.
But when I try to execute it on the test server, those errors occur.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting your txManager explicitly:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("net.myproject.db")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
  ...


  @Override
 public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
     return transactionManager();
 }

}
```

Comment: I tried but complained about multiple TransactionManagementConfigurers; when I delved further, I found that I had both spring-data as well as spring-orm/dao referred in my pom. Removing spring-data solved the original problem but someday I will have to use spring-data.

Answer (score 1):

Right `implements TransactionManagementConfigurer` works, but Spring 4.0 is more tolerant and now `TransactionInterceptor` determines `PlatformTransactionManager` at runtime from `BeanFactory`. The part of `@EnableTransactionManagement` JavaDocs:

> - {@code @EnableTransactionManagement} is more flexible; it will fall back to a by-type
> - lookup for any {@code PlatformTransactionManager} bean in the container. Thus the name
> - can be "txManager", "transactionManager", or "tm": it simply does not matter.

The `implements TransactionManagementConfigurer` is needed now, if you have several TxManager beans and it is really require to provide only one of them to the `TransactionInterceptor.

So, your configuration is OK and works as is with Spring 4.0

Answer (score 1):

you should change your AppConfig:

```
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceStatdb());
    sessionFactory.setMapperLocations( new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:mybatis/query/*.xml"));
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
}
```

to

```
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceStatdb());
    sessionFactory.setMapperLocations( new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:mybatis/query/*.xml"));
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove spring-dao.jar from project. Spring-tx.jar an spring-dao.jar has class TransactionAspectSupport